# Avoiding duplication when defining specialised template class constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Suppose I have a template class:

```
template<typename T>
class Widget {
public:
    Widget(const std::string& name, int i) : t_(name),  cf_(name), ci_(i) {}
private:
    T t_;
    const Foo cf_;
    const int ci_;
}
```

And suppose, in this context, `T` will only be `Foo` or `int`. Anything other than `Widget<Foo>` and `Widget<int>` is nonsense in this context.

The constructor declared above works fine for `Widget<Foo>`. Is there a way I can define a specialised constructor for `Widget<int>`, which assigns to `t_` differently, but **without copy-pasting the initialisation of `cf_` and `ci_`?**

Something similar in spirit to the call to `Base(a)` in `Derived::Derived(int a, int b) : Base(a), b_(b) {}` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag dispatching, and forwarding constructor may help

```
template <typename> struct Tag {};


template<typename T>
class Widget {
public:
    Widget(const std::string& name, int i) : Widget(Tag<T>{}, name, i) {}

private:
    Widget(Tag<int>, const std::string& name, int i) :
        Widget(Tag<void>{}, 42, name, i)
    {}

    Widget(Tag<Foo>, const std::string& name, int i) :
        Widget(Tag<void>{}, name, name, i)
    {}

    template <typename U>
    Widget(Tag<void>, U&& u, const std::string& name, int i) :
         t_(std::forward<U>(u)),
         cf_(name),
         ci_(i)
    {}

private:
    T t_;
    const Foo cf_;
    const int ci_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Specializing the entire `Widget<int>` class is one option. Short of that, there are various approaches that can be used to avoid specializing the entire class; however they depend heavily on exactly how you need to construct it.

For this example, let's say that for `Widget<Foo>` you want to construct the class member `t_`, which will be a `Widget` using the `std::string name` parameter (`Widget` has a constructor that takes a `std::string` parameter), and for `Widget<int>` you want to construct the class member `t_` which will now be an `int` using the `int i` parameter.

First, define a specialized helper template function that picks the right parameter:

```
template<typename T>
auto t_param(const std::string &name, int i);

template<>
auto t_param<Foo>(const std::string &name, int i)
{
    return name;
}

template<>
auto t_param<int>(const std::string &name, int i)
{
    return i;
}
```

With this in place, your constructor becomes simply:

```
Widget(const std::string& name, int i)
        : t_(t_param<T>(name, i)),  cf_(name), ci_(i) {}
```